# How to get two form input values to Javascript console.log

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form composed of two fields.
Once the form filled, I'd like to get the two fields in a console.log that would display 'Field 1 ' + field1 + 'Field 2 ' + field2.
I know how to make it to display the value of one field but I'm getting stuck on doing this in two fields..

How would it be possible to complete this ?

Here is the HTML part :

```
<form name="Test">

<div class="form-group col-md-9">
<label for="inputState">Field1</label>
<select id="sel-inv" name="sel-inv" class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option> 
    <?php
    while($data1 = pg_fetch_array($queryInv)) 
        { 
        echo ("<option value=". $data1['gid'].">". $data1['gid']. "</option>"); 
        }
    ?>                                              
</select>
</div>

<div id="nom-dossier" class="form-group col-md-4">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1">Field2</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom-dossier-sel" name="nom-dossier-sel">
</div>

</form>
```

And that's the JS part :

```
<script>
document.getElementById('sel-inv').addEventListener('input', function() {
var field1 = this.value;
console.log ('Field 1 ' + field1);
});
</script>
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: `sel-inv` is `field1`, but what is `field2` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form element has all the values with their names.

```js
document.getElementById("form").onchange = function(e){

  var form = e.target.form;
  console.log(form["sel-inv"].value, form["nom-dossier-sel"].value);
  
}
```

```html
<form name="Test" id="form">

<div class="form-group col-md-9">
<label for="inputState">Field1</label>
<select id="sel-inv" name="sel-inv" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">1</option> 
    <option value="2">2</option> 
                                               
</select>
</div>

<div id="nom-dossier" class="form-group col-md-4">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1">Field2</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nom-dossier-sel">
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This modified code will do as requested:

```
document.getElementById('sel-inv').addEventListener('input', function() {
  var field1 = this.value;
  let field2 = document.getElementById(‘nom-dossier-sel’).value;
  console.log ('Field 1 ' + field1 + ' Field 2 ' + field2);
});
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25918083)

Comment: I updated the above to make it more clear that the question was answered. Better?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a custom `data attribute` to all field and on change of any field you can get the element by `queryselector` of `data-field`

**OR**

Recommended using actually `id` or `class` to get properties. You will have more control.

```js
document.getElementById("sel-inv").addEventListener("change", function () {
  const [f1, f2] = Array.from(
    document.querySelector("form").querySelectorAll("[data-field='field']")
  );
  console.log(f1, f2);
});
```

```html
<form name="Test">
    <div class="form-group col-md-9">
      <label for="inputState">Field1</label>
      <select id="sel-inv" name="sel-inv" class="form-control" data-field="field">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="nom-dossier" class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Field2</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom-dossier-sel" name="nom-dossier-sel" data-field="field">
    </div>

  </form>
```